# next page button on ng-grid does a post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I've created my first ng-grid table and loading it with data asynchronously from the server. All my code seems to get executed created and function as desired behind the scenes except for one major problem.

ng-grid's pagination buttons get rendered in HTML as 'button' tags like this:

```
<button class="ngPagerButton" ng-click="pageForward()" ng-disabled="cantPageForward()" title="Next Page">
    <div class="ngPagerLastTriangle ngPagerNextTriangle"></div>
</button>
```

But there is no type attribute put on the button so it defaults to type='submit'.

Whenever I click on the next page button, behind the scenes everything works, but it also does an extraneous POST because of the button type. This is completely undesired.

Anyone else run into this? How do you get around it? Am I doing something wrong?

The basic setup is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id='deposits' class='gridStyle' ng-grid='gridOptions'></div>
```

JS controller code (really nothing special here, taken pretty much right from the ng-grid docs...but not working!):

```
$scope.reportingForm = {
  startDate: new Date(2014, 1, 1),  // just for testing
  endDate: new Date(2014, 1, 7),
};

$scope.filterOptions = {
  filterText: '',
  useExternalFilter: true
};

$scope.totalServerItems = 0;
$scope.pagingOptions = {
  pageSizes: [7, 14],
  pageSize: 7,
  currentPage: 1
};

$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize) {  
  var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
  $scope.data = pagedData;
  $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
  if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
  }
};

$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page, searchText) {
  setTimeout(function () {
      var data;
      if (searchText) {
        var filter = searchText.toLowerCase();

        myService.getDataAsync(
          $scope.reportingForm.startDate, $scope.reportingForm.endDate
          function(result) {
            data = result.result.data.filter(function(item) {
              return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
            });

            $scope.setPagingData(data, page, pageSize);
          }
        );          
      } else {
        myService.getDataAsync(
          $scope.reportingForm.startDate, $scope.reportingForm.endDate,
          function(result) {
            $scope.setPagingData(result.result.data, page, pageSize);
          }
        );
      }
  }, 100);
};

$scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
  }
}, true);

$scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
  }
}, true);

$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'data',
  pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
  filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
  enablePaging: true,
  showFooter: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'date', displayName: 'Date' },
    { field: 'id', displayName: 'Id' },
    { field: 'location', displayName: 'Location' },
    { field: 'amount', displayName: 'Amount' },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-grid renders the previous and next page buttons as <button> and does not specify a button type so it defaults to type='submit'.

In our page the ng-grid table lived within a form. I didn't know this but after some testing realized submit <button>s within a form do a POST, but submit <button>s outside of a form do NOT do a POST.

By moving our ng-grid table outside of the form we no longer have this problem.

Really though, this seems to be an oversight in the ng-grid code. It should really be rendering the buttons as type='button' to prevent this kind of issue in the future. I can't imagine any cases where you'd want the last/next page buttons to do POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed in ng-grid 2.0.8 whenever it is released. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/pull/693